# Could not compile YAF.NET v2.2.2 source code in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, yetanotherforum

I took latest code from http://www.yetanotherforum.net/download this url.
steps:

1. Go to the url http://www.yetanotherforum.net/download
2. Click on "Source Package" of the first block
   The version the release is YAF.NET v2.2.2.
3. Unzip YAFNET-2.2.2.Zip folder
4. Open the solution using Visual studio 2013 (my one is ultimate version)
5. Build the solution you will get lots of error

I could not fix this. Can any one please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are right. I need to restore all the packages from neget however it was not doing automatically. I have solve the problem getting package folder from github. and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting?

I guess you need to Restore all the Packages via Nuget.